# Why does "wmi.WMI()" print "<_wmi_namespace: <COMObject winmgmts:>>"?

Tags: python, wmi

When run `wmi.WMI()` I am getting this "<_wmi_namespace: >" anyone explain this?

```py
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
```

output:

```
<_wmi_namespace: <COMObject winmgmts:>>
```

Can anyone explain in-detail?

Answer (score 0):

`wmi` is "Windows Management Instrumentation".  It is essentially a huge database of internal information about your Windows system.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-reference